# Cannot bind prefix-less command exclusively to uppercase letter (C-H vs. C-h)

Tags: tmux

I have the following prefix-less key bindings in my `tmux.conf`.

```
bind -n C-J swap-window -t -1
bind -n C-K swap-window -t +1
bind -n C-H select-window -p
bind -n C-L select-window -n
```

These bindings are activated by the intended C-H, C-L, etc. The problem is that they are also activated by their lowercase counterparts, i.e. C-h, C-l, etc., which is interfering with command line key bindings. Why would this not be working as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most terminals just do not distinguish between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> – the resulting input always has the same bits unset (0x6f `o` or 0x4f `O` → 0x0f `^O`).

You can verify this using `stty cbreak; xxd -c1` and pressing various combinations of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>; you'll see the program seeing everything as `0x0f`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for this, and especially for the verification command. I've decided to use the meta key instead since it is distinguishable.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently some terminal emulators provide an option via .Xdefaults/.Xresources to modify specific keycodes.

I currently have the following in my .Xdefaults and it works with urxvt like a charm:

```
URxvt*keysym.Shift-Prior: string:\002[
URxvt*keysym.Shift-Up: string:cd ..\n
URxvt*keysym.Shift-Down: string:cd --\n
```

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50205/map-control-shift-tab-in-rxvt-unicode)